# open image in a new tab

Tags: php, html

Here I am stuck again. I want to open my image in a new tab when clicked. so i have put the image in between  tag. but it's not working.Can't understand what i am doing wrong. any help please?

```
while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s">';
            echo '<div class="border">';
            $link = "localhost/fiberglass/" .$query_row['link'];
            echo '<a href="localhost/fiberglass/.$query_row['link']">';
            echo '<img style="width:100%;height:auto" src="' . $link . '" />'; 
            echo '</a>';
            echo '<div class="text-center imgname">';
            echo $query_row['link'];
            echo '</div>'; 
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';

            }
```

Comment: should i remove the link from <a> tag ? because its generating a punctuation error. and i tried target="_blank".. it's not working .

Comment: target="_blank" will solve your problem

Comment: You're getting an error because your href= is wrong. See @chris85 's answer for a thorough cleaning of what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Check updated answer, think it should work. You had a concatenation issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give the link a target so it loads into a new window/tab.

```
while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s">';
            echo '<div class="border">';
            $link = "localhost/fiberglass/" .$query_row['link'];
            echo '<a href="localhost/fiberglass/' .$query_row['link'] . '" target="_blank">';
            echo '<img style="width:100%;height:auto" src="' . $link . '" />'; 
            echo '</a>';
            echo '<div class="text-center imgname">';
            echo $query_row['link'];
            echo '</div>'; 
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';

            }
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

> Target:
>   This attribute specifies where to display the linked resource. In HTML4, this is the name of, or a keyword for, a frame. In HTML5, it is a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context (for example, tab, window, or inline frame). The following keywords have special meanings:
>   _self: Load the response into the same HTML4 frame (or HTML5 browsing context) as the current one. This value is the default if the attribute is not specified.
>   **_blank: Load the response into a new unnamed HTML4 window or HTML5 browsing context.**
>   _parent: Load the response into the HTML4 frameset parent of the current frame or HTML5 parent browsing context of the current one. If there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as _self.
>   _top: In HTML4: Load the response into the full, original window, canceling all other frames. In HTML5: Load the response into the top-level browsing context (that is, the browsing context that is an ancestor of the current one, and has no parent). If there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as _self.

You also had a concatenation error in your link construction.

Also `$link` appears to be the same as `localhost/fiberglass/' .$query_row['link'] . '`. Could just use `$link` there.

Comment: taget="_blank" should be target

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="2s">';
            echo '<div class="border">';
            $link = "localhost/fiberglass/" .$query_row['link'];
            echo '<a href="localhost/fiberglass/.$query_row['link']" target="_blank">';
            echo '<img style="width:100%;height:auto" src="' . $link . '" />'; 
            echo '</a>';
            echo '<div class="text-center imgname">';
            echo $query_row['link'];
            echo '</div>'; 
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<a>` tag you need to add `'target='_blank'`